# Why does this display the values in the row above instead of the formula specified if there is only one row of data?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a snippet from my macro and its supposed to input the formula specified from Row 4 down to the end of the dataset. However, when the dataset provided only has one row of data (data starts in row 4) instead of the formula, it just picks up the value in the cell one row above. IE: R4 will show R3 instead of "=IF(RC[-11]>RC[-10],(RC[-8]*RC[-11])-(RC[-8]*RC[-10]),0)"

```
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-5]),RC[14],RC[1])": Range("I4:I" & Lastrow).FillDown
    Range("R4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]>RC[-10],(RC[-8]*RC[-11])-(RC[-8]*RC[-10]),0)": Range("R4:R" & Lastrow).FillDown
    Range("AA4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-19]*RC[-18]": Range("AA4:AA" & Lastrow).FillDown
```

I came up with a work around, however I'm curious as to why this happened in the first place.

```
    If Lastrow = 4 Then
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-5]),RC[14],RC[1])"
    Range("R4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]>RC[-10],(RC[-8]*RC[-11])-(RC[-8]*RC[-10]),0)"
    Range("AA4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-19]*RC[-18]"
    Else
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-5]),RC[14],RC[1])": Range("I4:I" & Lastrow).FillDown
    Range("R4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]>RC[-10],(RC[-8]*RC[-11])-(RC[-8]*RC[-10]),0)": Range("R4:R" & Lastrow).FillDown
    Range("AA4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-19]*RC[-18]": Range("AA4:AA" & Lastrow).FillDown
    End If
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use (eg) `Range("I4").FormulaR1C1 = ...`  No need to select anything

Comment: Plus you don't need to `FillDown`: `Range("I4:I" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = ...`.